# How to uninstall 3rd party keyboards on ios8

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios, third-party

I've installed a 3rd party keyboard on ios8. I didn't like it so i wanted to uninstall it completely.  It stills appear under "Third Party Keyboards" when I press "Add new Keyboard..." in the Keyboards settings.

Any hints how to make it disappear at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only disable it in the General -> Keyboard section. To delete it, you have to delete the application that provides it.